# Gnome icons load instead of Suede

Tags: icons, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 12.04.1 on a 64bit machine. I'm trying to change my icons to the suede set, but only the gnome icons load. I've tried installing the suede theme manually by downloading it from gnome-look.org and extracting to /usr/share/icons/ and also by installing via Synaptic. The preview in lxappearance of gnome and suede remain identical, and the icons used when applying the theme are as well.
I tried editing the index.theme file so that suede would not inherit gnome by deleting the "Inherits" line, but there was no effect. After every change I made, I would log out and back in or reboot to check.
I even tried copying the desktop icon from suede to gnome and used the Gimp to resize the file for each instance in gnome. This changed it in the lxappearance preview but not in pcmanfm's side pane. I have not had the problem with other themes, only suede.
Has any one else had this problem? And/or have a solution?

Comment: Is it possible that the Set doens't have all the Icons?...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tutorial provided by GNOME [here](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/IconThemes) which teaches you everything about icon themes.

Comment: Suede had all its category folders within a "scalable" folder. I tried putting them in the same folder as the index.theme and edited it's directory list accordingly. There was no effect. I also tried removing the gnome "filesystem" directory references within the index file. Still no fix.

Comment: You'll have to update the `index.theme` file. See the updated answer.

Comment: I did. That is what I meant by "edited it's directory list accordingly." I also updated each bracketed directory listing.

Comment: I'll try it in Lubuntu and get back to you.

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: try exporting those scalable files into .png and seperate them by size (22,24,32,48,64,96)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll go through the tutorial and also try exporting into definite size png-s.

Comment: Still no fix...

Comment: The tutorial link is broken.